# Apple Pages (desktop) - clear previous documents?

Tags: imac, security, pages

For years I’ve created and used a Pages template document that contains the various document and font settings I regularly use. This makes it easier to begin writing right away. I usually forget to duplicate and rename the document until a later stage in writing.

It is handy to have Pages store previous draft versions for the purpose of “reverting” if necessary, but I wish to clear all previous versions of a document (or all Pages documents) for privacy purposes.

How can that be done?

Pages 11.1
Big Sur
iMac intel

Comment: Have you checked whether a Duplicate or Save As contain Revisions? Also, if you Save your starting document as an 'actual' Template (so you can choose it from the template chooser), then duplicate/renaming will not be an issue.

Comment: You wouldn't need to worry about duplicating and renaming documents if you use a custom template. See the "[Create a custom template in Pages on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/pages/create-a-custom-template-tan526e83fd0/12.0/mac/1.0)" Apple support webpage for more.

Comment: thanks, but the issue is about clearing previous versions under the Revert > Browse All Versions.

Comment: thanks, but the issue is about clearing all previous versions under the Revert > Browse All Versions, for privacy purposes... and not about using templates.  That was just an example of my workflow. However, even after creating a Template as suggested, and making it available in the Template Chooser, the issue is the same. Think of the Previous Versions as a "document cache" to be purged. We have various tools to purge cache files from other apps... how do I do that with the Pages cache of previous documents of the same filename?